# How to get some information from WebView

Tags: android, http

I must develop an Android Application that open certain urls in a Webview , but i have some problem :

1. When i try to open mobile site ( `m.site.something.it` ) an intent
   start , wondering which browser i want use to open the web site.

   I want force the opening of each site in a webview ( NO broweser ) .
2. I need to intercept all `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` all , how i can
   do this ?

I'm developing for **Android 6.0** , to post olds using deprecated method .

### EDIT

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String urlToLoad = intent.getStringExtra("url");

        // webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        //THIS SHOULD FORCE OPEN SITE IN WV, BUT NOT WORK
        webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");

        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

        webview.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
```

***** EDIT 2 *****

Another problem is :
 2. I need to intercept all `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` all , how i can
    do this ?

Comment: We ned to see some code for this.

Comment: @zgc7009 i have edited

Comment: Does it open an intent chooser for every site or just the mobile ones?

Comment: Site like : http://m.mitsubushi-motors.de/

Comment: But does www.mitsubushi-motors.de?

Comment: No, intent started

Comment: So you are calling webview.loadUrl(urlToLoad) ad the intent chooser is popping up? That seems weird. Trying dropping the UserAgentString.

Comment: @MikeM. if you read what I wrote, you would have noticed that I have already adopted the solution in the link you attached

Comment: @Alessia Please indicate exactly where it is in your question that you mention setting a `WebViewClient` on the `WebView`, because I don't see it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this on your code:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```